# Concurrent blocking map with entries eviction

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, guava

What I need is a fairly complex data structure with the following requirements:

1. It should support concurrent reads/writes without any excessive locking (like `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`)
2. It should have capacity limit and block once the limit is reached (just like `BlockingQueue` implementations)
3. It should have efficient search mechanism, like `Map`/`HashSet` do: given an ID of an object, I need to be able to find it without sequential scan.
4. It should be possible to evict elements on timeout, for instance: if an entry is put in this structure more than `X` minutes ago, it should be automatically removed.

Of course, there's always a chance to implement it on my own, but I'd prefer to find something existing, optimized and well-tested.

The only thing that's near is Guava's cache, but it seems to be missing #2. Any ideas on known implementations of this?

Comment: What should it be optimized _for_?

Comment: You are asking for some thing very similar to a cache, indeed. I have a similar request right now and I came across Google ConcurrentLinkedHashMap / Caffeine. It seems very promising. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple BlockingCache, which wraps an existing Guava Cache and checks capacity on `put` operations, so the put would look something like this:

```
public V put(K key, V value)
{
    while (size() >= capacity) Thread.sleep(100);
    return innerCache.put(key, value);
}
```